# Magento 2 custom theme CSS and other resources not loading

Tags: magento2.2.3, luma-theme, custom-theme

I have setup Magento 2 in local system in WAMP stack.
We have two websites.
One is our Main website and other is different domain webiste.

First website working fine with Luma theme and url is **abc.com**.
I have created new website and created virtual host for the same.

But when I run virtual host **url xyz.com** it's running perfectly but **css** and other resources not loading. It **gives an error like failed to load resources.**

Also I have check **pub/static** all the files available.

See screenshots.

**abc.com default website**

[image]

**xyz.com new website with new custom theme**

[image]

I have run below command as well.

```
  php bin/magento setup:upgrade
  php -dmemory_limit=5G bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f
```

But default website working fine only.

My virtual host configuration like below.

Please help me.

Comment: this may help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22561424/magento-multiple-store-views-cannot-get-css-and-js-files-for-new-stores

Comment: Thanks for the reply but I am using magento 2.